# Spikes are not showing correctly in Highstock

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a question regarding Highstock. I am having a data recording Engine Load which has spikes in the dataset. I am trying to chart this dataset in Highstock, but when the input data range is large (to a certain point) then the spikes won't be showing correctly in the chart. Attached are the images for better explanation.

Showing correctly when the date range is not large:
[image]
**NOT** showing correctly when the data range is large:
[image]

The two images are charting from the same dataset just with different range of time.
Why this would happen in Highstock and how to get it fixed?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this has to do with HighStock doing some sort of aggregation when zoom in out/in past a certain threshold. This can be turned off by setting something like this:

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        dataGrouping: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
}
```

This tells HighStock to stop grouping x-Axis points together to get aggregates.
Check [here](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/ref/#plotOptions-series-dataGrouping) for more info in dataGrouping.

Comment: Exactly what I want! Thank you very much.

Comment: Not a problem. I highly recommend their API documentation. It is very cool and well designed with jsFiddle examples for most. There are, of course, undocumented elements but the important bits are right at your fingertips at the URL I provided.